# Need help in deploying my python flask API in Jetty or tomcat

Tags: python, tomcat, flask, deep-learning, jetty

I am fresher looking to deploy my python flask API in Jetty or tomcat.

No idea how to do that first time to the deployment. I tested it postman wsgi server getting the output.

No idea about how to move ahead.

Comment: I have the same problem. I would like to deploy my python flask API in tomcat. Would you be able to resolve this? If not, what server did you try to deploy? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For flask applications, you do not use Jetty or Tomcat which are web servers majorly for Java applications. Compatible webservers for Flask would be using either of Gunicorn, uWSGI, Gevent, Twisted Web documented [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone).

For most use cases, Gunicorn would suffice as a web server. You could check out the gunicorn documentation [here](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/) or DigitalOcean's tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)